# Websphere The time stamp value occurs too far into the future

Tags: web-services, websphere, websphere-7, ws-security, usernametoken

I have set Username token webservice security and deployed this application on Websphere 7.0 app server. I have set below properties to false:

com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.verifyNonce false
com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.token.username.verifyTimestamp false

Even after setting above properties, the client gets below error message:

security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: CWWSS5208E: The time stamp value occurs too far into the future. ocurred while running action:

Can someone please help me to get rid of this error?

Is there any property that can be set for the allowable permissible time difference? or is there any property that can be set in webservice bindings to get rid of this error?

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: have you checked the system time on both systems already?

Comment: Ideally Client of the webservice can have different timezone,timings.                @Stefan ::do u mean that client and server should have clocks in syn?

Comment: yes. even with different timezones the time should and would be send in UTC. If the server has a clock which is too far away from the real time I would expect something like this could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have verifyTimestamp and verifyNonce turned off, this error probably from the Timestamp element.  Do you have a Timestamp in your Security header?  I think that if the error is for the Created in the UsernameToken, you'd get this error:

CWWSS5209E: The time stamp value for the nonce, which is a randomly generated value, occurs too far into the future.

The default clockskew is 3 minutes.  If you need it to be longer, you can set it with this custom property in the ws-security bindings:

com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.TimestampClockSkew

The value is in seconds.  You set it here:

(open your bindings) > WS-Security > Custom properties

Since its an inbound custom property, you can put it under 'inbound custom properties' or 'inbound and outbound custom properties'

The property for the clockskew for the UsernameToken Created is 
com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.config.token.BasicAuth.Nonce.clockSkew and it is configured in the general custom properties described above.

As said before though, the best thing to do is to synchronize your clocks.  I understand the motivation to increase the clockskew though; one of our servers had a 'drifty' clock.  We eventually solved the problem by adding a cron job to sync the clock with our registry (that has a time service) every day.